# What happens when I use ssh command as command substitution in echo

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I went little crazy...

Here's what I did

```
 echo `ssh root@10.42.0.1`
```

Then it asked for password and I entered it and later it was struck there.

I expect that echo is blocked here. Is it correct?

Please explain what happened exactly here in a step-by-step way.

Answer (score 4):

> I expect that echo is blocked here. Is it correct?

A command substitution is always processed before the "final" (in this case "outer") command is run.

So `echo` is not "blocked", but is waiting for the command inside the command substitution to finish its execution, which never happens because the command itself spawns an `ssh` interactive shell.

You can verify this in multiple ways, for example by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, by typing `exit` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or by opening another terminal instance and running:

```
pkill -15 -x ssh
```

As you can see, terminating the `ssh` instance by any mean will let the command substitution finish its execution, finally letting the `echo` command run on its output, which in this case is nothing.

Comment: but here irrespective of the first echo the result is same

Comment: @RamanaReddy I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @RamanaReddy I've changed the example, see if this one makes more sense

Comment: @adonis Done, now it's explicit

Comment: I don't think you need to kill it. Pressing Ctrl-D, or, typing `exit` and pressing Enter, etc., should be enough.